# Disconnected: no supported authentication methods available

Tags: putty, authentication, sshd, ssh-keys

I have the same exact problem described in [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/189151/ssh-key-based-authentication-fails), but the answer accepted there is not the right one for me, because the user's home directory **is** local.

I think that I configured everything properly on the client side (Windows 7, PuTTY's PAGEANT, PUTTYGEN and PLINK), yet I don't seem to make the public key mechanism work (password based ssh login works). I followed all the steps, cues and hints in:

- [How To Configure SSH Keys Authentication With PuTTY And Linux Server
  In 5 Quick Steps](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-configure-ssh-keys-authentication-with-putty-and-linux-server-in-5-quick-steps)
- [SSH Public Key Authentication](http://www.cs.uwaterloo.ca/cscf/howto/ssh/public_key/#putty)

I now suspect that I may be missing something on the server side (Linux, sshd), so I am posting the current `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` content:

```
Protocol 2
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding yes
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** I found a tip for running [sshd in debug mode](https://superuser.com/questions/150532/ssh-authentification-with-public-key-fails/196839#196839), and here is the output:

```
/home/winwin> /usr/sbin/sshd -d
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_4.2p1
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: private host key: #0 type 1 RSA
debug1: read PEM private key done: type DSA
debug1: private host key: #1 type 2 DSA
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-d'
debug1: Bind to port 22 on ::.
Server listening on :: port 22.
debug1: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0.
Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0 failed: Address already in use.
debug1: Server will not fork when running in debugging mode.
debug1: rexec start in 4 out 4 newsock 4 pipe -1 sock 7
debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
Connection from 192.168.1.8 port 49828
debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version PuTTY_Release_0.60
debug1: no match: PuTTY_Release_0.60
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.2
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 74/74
debug1: list_hostkey_types: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: client->server aes256-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: kex: server->client aes256-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST_OLD received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: KEX done

debug1: userauth-request for user winwin service ssh-connection method none
debug1: attempt 0 failures 0
debug1: PAM: initializing for "winwin"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "win7client"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
Failed none for winwin from 192.168.1.8 port 49828 ssh2
debug1: userauth-request for user winwin service ssh-connection method publickey
debug1: attempt 1 failures 1
debug1: test whether pkalg/pkblob are acceptable
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 513/513 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /home/winwin/.ssh/authorized_keys
Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/winwin
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 513/513 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /home/winwin/.ssh/authorized_keys
Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/winwin
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Failed publickey for winwin from 192.168.1.8 port 49828 ssh2
Received disconnect from 192.168.1.8: 14: No supported authentication methods available
debug1: do_cleanup
debug1: PAM: cleanup
debug1: do_cleanup
debug1: PAM: cleanup
```

Now, I do notice the two `bad ownership or modes for directory /home/winwin` messages but I checked the ownership or modes for directory /home/winwin and AFAICT they're OK:

```
/home> ls -lad winwin
drwxrwxr-x  21 winwin winwin 4096 Jul 13 21:24 winwin
```

And:

```
/home/winwin> ls -lad .ssh
drwxr-xr-x  2 winwin winwin 4096 Jul 14 12:06 .ssh
```

And:

```
/home/winwin/.ssh> ls -lad *
-rw-r--r--  1 winwin winwin 210 Jul 14 12:06 authorized_keys
-rw-r--r--  1 winwin winwin 210 Jul 14 01:58 authorized_keys.pub
-rw-r--r--  1 winwin winwin 394 Jul 14 01:57 authorized_keys.pub.orig
```

What could possibly be wrong?

**UPDATE II:** I tried `chmod 600` as suggested in the answer below:

```
/home/winwin> ls -lad .ssh
drw-------  2 winwin winwin 4096 Jul 14 13:13 .ssh
```

And:

```
/home/winwin/.ssh> ls -lad *
-rw-------  1 winwin winwin 210 Jul 14 12:06 authorized_keys
```

But it still doesn't work. Why am I still getting the `Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/winwin` error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Success!

All I had to do is change `StrictModes` to **no**.

Per [section 3.14](http://www.openssh.org/faq.html#3.14) in the OpenSSH FAQ and http://blogs.nullvision.com/?p=114 .

Wow.

Comment: Hmm, that's more of a workaround than a solution, though. Let me check something on my box.

Comment: My `ls -lad .ssh` is showing drwx, so `chmod 700 ~/.ssh` and the files inside are all -rw, so `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*` -SHOULD- work.

Comment: Nevermind, saw *The home directory of this user must be writeable by the group (having same exact name and gid!)* below

Comment: This way is userless!

Answer (score 9):

Try taking the group writeable permissions from your home directory:

```
chmod g-w ~/
```

Make your .ssh folder readable/writeable/executable **only by you**:

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
```

Make your authorized keys file readable/writeable **only by you**:

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

That should remove the permissions errors.

Comment: I did just as you suggested for `~/.ssh` and `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. Still no luck. As for taking the group writeable permissions from the home directory itself, I can't do that as it would undermine the entire purpose of this user/group has been created for. The home directory of this user must be writeable by the group (having same exact name and gid!). +1 for attempting to help.

Comment: Thank you! `chmod g-w ~/` saved me after hours of madness and hair pulling when I could not ssh with putty on behalf of one of users, with other users working ok...

Comment: Gah ya thanks, I created my home directory with my other user, and I was missing chmod g-w ~/

Answer (score 3):

Had a similar issue.  When poking around I noticed that I had my home directories encrypted, and suspected that was the issue.  I copied the authorized keys file to a directory outside of the encrypted home directory, changed the permissions appropriately (chmod 700 [dir], chmod 600 [dir]/authorized_keys, etc.).

Then edit your sshd_config to tell sshd of the new location for the authorized keys file, restart sshd, and that's it.

Seems to have fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your permissions for the home directory (or possibly your .ssh/authorized_keys folder) are incorrect. Correcting those should fix the login issue. Try `chmod 600 /home/winwin/.ssh/*`
You might need to `chmod 700 /home/winwin/.ssh` as well.

SSHd will refuse to load your `authorized_keys` file if it can be written to by anyone other than your user (as the owner) because it's a security risk.

Comment: Thanks +1. See my update above, as I still can't figure out what the correct permissions/ownership should be.

Comment: I just tried `chmod 600 /home/winwin/.ssh/*`. It didn't help. :-/

Comment: @WinWin did you set it on the `.ssh` directory as well? (I updated my answer).

Comment: Yes, I did. Still no luck.

Answer (score 2):

I struggled through this and finally found a solution which doesn't cause a potential security breach like **StrictModes *No*** does.

Make sure your settings are as follows:

> chmod 0755 /home/**{userdir}**
>
> chmod 0700 /home/**{userdir}**/.ssh
>
> chmod 0600 /home/**{userdir}**/.ssh/authorized_keys

Where {userdir} is the directory in question.

The key is chmod 0755 which ensures that only the user can write to the home drive. I copied this from my user config that worked, and, *presto!* The other usernames started working too!

Hope this helps others like it did me, and saves you a couple hours of time.

Answer (score 1):

This error message can also be caused by SELinux preventing sshd from accessing `authorized_keys`. Try this:

```
restorecon -FRvv ~/.ssh
```

(from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20818775/33080))

Answer (score 0):

```
chown -R winwin.winwin /home/winwin/
chmod 700 /home/winwin/
find /home/winwin/ -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;
find /home/winwin/ -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \;
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! It'd be nice if you could explain what these commands do.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the **home directory which had another owner** (root) than the actual user to which this home directory belongs to (my stupidity when creating the home dir with root for another user).

```
Chown [user]:[group] /home/[user]
```

has solved this issue (and of course stick to the file/dir permissions as shared in other answers).